# how to read HTML structure from string and map attribute values to local variables in angular2

Tags: html, html-parsing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have an HTML tag retried from database which holds some attribute.
To specify with example :
I have this HTML string as :

```
<CoinsNotesSelector  items='0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1'   label='Available coins'  mode='Select'></CoinsNotesSelector>
```

now i want values of items , labels and mode by reading/parsing this tag.

is there something available for parsing the custom HTML tags.

Comment: Can you post your `CoinsNotesSelectorComponent`? You can get your values from there. Also, have a look at the Heroes tutorial on Angular (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) to learn more about angular 2

Comment: hi John ,the CoinsNotesSelector  is just a custom tag , its not a component , you can consider it as "XML" tag , i just want to read and get value of attribute within this tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your html-element in your code and only want to read the attributes, you can do a simple vanilla javascript method:

```
var rawItems = document.getElementsByTagName("CoinsNotesSelector")[0].getAttribute("items");
var items = rawItems.split(",");
console.log("my items",items);
```

You can change the `attributeName` inside `getAttribute(attributeName)` in order to get your other attributes such as label and mode as well.

There is no need to do any Angular2 stuff for the question you are asking. 
However, you could create your own component in angular 2 and use `@Input()`-decorator in order to read the items directly.

***EDIT***
After understanding more about the question, it seems that the html is a raw string.

You can extract the items using regular expression.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var str = "<CoinsNotesSelector  items='0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1'   label='Available coins'  mode='Select'></CoinsNotesSelector>"; 
        var myRegExpItems = /items='([\.\,0-9]+)'/g;
        var myRegExpLabel = /label='([\ a-zA-Z0-9]+)'/g;
        var match = myRegExpItems.exec(str);
        document.getElementById("myItems").innerHTML = match[1];
        console.log("match", match[1].split(","));
        match= myRegExpLabel.exec(str);
        document.getElementById("myLabel").innerHTML = match[1];
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Run</button>
<div>items: <span id="myItems"></span></div>
<div>label: <span id="myLabel"></span></div>
```

What we do is grouping the results within the `items`-attribute, looking for all numbers, commas, and periods, and then extracting the result into our `match`-variable. This variable will be an array with all of our matches. Similarly with the `label`-attribute. Match for space, all numbers and all letters. Now, this work well when you only have simple strings. If you have a larger file containing many html-elements formatted as strings, I suggest using an xml/html-parser or similar.

Comment: Thanks John , this was helpful , however as I mentioned in the question as well , my HTML was a string ( basically some other system creates it as a user input using HTML editor , stores it in DB and I retrieve it from DB ). I was doing something similar , only diff was instead of document I was trying to use the string, but it didn't work . Thats why I posted this question so as to , if we have any option to read HTML/XML tags for attribute value.